# How to avoid deadlock inside transaction?

Tags: mysql, innodb, transaction, deadlock

I have a transaction that wraps two code paths that update/insert related tables in the opposite order. Outside of a transaction I understand why that would cause a deadlock, but why does it happen inside a transaction? I must be misunderstanding the **relationship between locks and transactions** (are they completely unrelated? What I had assumed was that the transaction would prevent parallel execution entirely).  Pseudo-code:

```
START TRANSACTION
    IF (SELECT something FROM table_1) THEN
        UPDATE table_2
        UPDATE table_1
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO table_1
        UPDATE table_2
    END IF
COMMIT
```

(I've done my best to reverse the order of the UPDATEs to avoid deadlock potential but I have a couple code paths where that is not a good option)

FYI: Error message is: `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction` and as far as I can tell is caused by more than one parallel process invoking the same DB call at the same time.

Comment: @mustaccio Of course, and notice the code paths in the pseudo code are mutually exclusive. The deadlock is due to multiple parallel calls into the same code at nearly the same time.

Comment: Does that `SELECT` have the `FOR UPDATE` clause on the end?

Comment: @RickJames No it does not. Is doing so advisable as a generic lock that I thought "START TRANSACTION" was doing? Does it lock the *transaction* even if the UPDATES are not against that table (or are against *more* than that table)?

Answer (score 1):

When a `SELECT` is "inside" a transaction (that is, between the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`),

Case 1:  The Select has nothing to do with the subsequent updates/inserts/deleted (inside the transaction).  It may as well be done before the `BEGIN`, thereby making the transaction run a little faster, hence a little less likely to collide with other connections.

Case 2:  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` -- This implies that you are checking something in the table in order to decide whether the row should be updated/etc.  The `FOR UPDATE` announces to other connections "Please do not change these row(s); I will get confused if you do."  This locking mechanism expires at `COMMIT`.

So, add `FOR UPDATE` and see if the problem is solved.

Are both connections performing the pseudo-code you listed?  If so...  The pairs of writing to table1 and table2 could, perhaps, be done in the same order.  This may turn a deadlock into a "lock wait"  (cf, `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`)

Comment: To be clear, it sounds like my assumption that START TRANSACTION provides protection against parallel execution was wrong? Transactions *only* guarantee the block is atomic?

Comment: Is using `FOR UPDATE` on table_1 sufficient as a lock even though table_2 is also being written?

Comment: What if there is no `SELECT`? Then how would one attain a lock and prevent deadlock?

Comment: @chell - Your example has a `SELECT`.  If you have a different example, please provide it.

Comment: Maybe replace the `if (SELECT)` with with `if (var = x)`

Comment: @chell - If you are checking data in one of the tables to decide which to do, you _need_ it to be transactional.  The "var" could be out of date?

Comment: Yes, and that line of thinking is what led me to assume the transaction would naturally also lock. The follow-up questions are an attempt to understand why a single table `FOR UPDATE` would be enough if multiple tables are being updated, and indeed, if the `IF` was based on a variable outside of table data (time of day, user role, may be some examples)

Comment: Maybe it becomes a separate question, but it's unclear if the locking would be correct if the `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` is different than the updates?

Comment: @chell - `SELECT` does not lock anything.  `SELECT..FOR UPDATE` locks the rows that are selected; the subsequent `UPDATE/DELETE does not need to modify/delete exactly the same set of rows.  That is, the `WHERE` is not remembered, only the rows it references.